# How to add image/mount/disk back to the sidebar?

Tags: finder, disk-utility

I accidentally dragged and removed an image/disk from the sidebar under the device. I can now only access this image under volumes folder, but I like to add it back to the sidebar. Is there a way to do it? (I can see it also in my diskutil. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press command shift G at the same time and go to `/Volumes`, then drag the folder and drop it to the sidebar. This will work when you cannot find the image on either your desktop and don't have a top level path saved in the finder's sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

Open the volume at the top level in Finder.

On the Finder menu select Add to Sidebar.

Alternatively, grab the icon on the desktop and drag it to where you want it in the sidebar list.